# This python code which uses dictionary comprehension with a conditional expression doesn't work

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

This python code doesn't work.
Why?
Any alternative code?
Thank you!

```
 def suppress(D, threshold):
     return {i:0 if x < threshold else i:x for (i, x) in D.items()}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional expressions **are expressions**, they requires two different expressions which evaluate to a value,

```
<expression 1> if <boolean expression> else <expression 2>
```

But `i:0` is not an expression, it is *part* of a dictionary display (which is an expression). But by itself, it will just be a syntax error.

You want:

```
{i: <conditional expression> for (i, x) in D.items()}
```

Or more completely,

```
{i: 0 if x < threshold else x for (i, x) in D.items()}
```

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga, Thank you very much for your perfect answer!